# Why can't I declare a const array? (not array of consts, but array, whose elements & size can't be changed)

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

**#upd:**  **Please, see "#UPDATED_2" below at first.**

I can't do it. No matter where I put the `const` keyword in the following code, I don't receive the desired result:

```
int arrayOfInts[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

The next two variants of the above code gives an array of consts:

```
const int arrayOfInts[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int const arrayOfInts[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

But I want to declare an **`const` array**, whose elements & size can't be changed.

Any other position of `const` keyword in this code doesn't satisfy the compiler.

**#UPDATED:** Sorry! Of course I wrote an stupidity about size of array. Certainly it can't be changed. So I need an array, whose elements can't be changed. I mean, nobody can do something like:

```
arrayOfInts[4] = 10;
```

**#UPDATED_2:** I'm very sorry! Obviosly I'm overheated.. Whole my question is stupidity! Elements of array of consts can't be changed!
I was misled by the fact that

```
std::array<Type1, arrayOfInts[4]> a;
```

doesn't compiled. For some reason I decided that, it's because of arrayOfInts[4] isn't const, but it isn't so. It's because of operator "[]" doesn't allowed in a template argument expression.
Please, forgive me for your lost time.

Comment: The size can't change as it is. This would offer nothing over an array of const elements.

Comment: There is no difference in `const int` and `int const`.

Comment: The declarations `const int arrayOfInts[5]=...;` and `int const arrayOfInts[5]=...;` have the same meaning.

Comment: You could always use `std::array` [see example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7907ddecbd44e0aa)

Comment: Just make an Array wrapper and make it immutable.

Comment: When declaring an array you are already assigning a block of memory that does not change. The block is a continuous block of whatever type the array consists of. If you wanted a mutable array you would have to use an `arraylist or vector`

Comment: C++ is statically typed, so once you have declared a variable, you can't change the type of it, it doesn't matter how you declare it. And as for the size, if you declare an array, the size is part of the type so that can't be changed either. In fact, the type of `arrayOfInts` for the last two variants is "array of five constant integers", so neither the type, size, nor the contents can be changed.

Comment: can you show an example of code modifying something if you declare it as you showed?

Comment: @chris: You need to combine that argument with the fact that you cannot assign arrays in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you have

```
int arrayOfInts[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

or

```
const int arrayOfInts[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

you can't change the size of the array. Size is a constant for both forms.

In the first one, you can change the elements of the array. In the second one you can't change the elements of the array.

The second declaration gives you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `const T x = /* some value */;`, or equivalently, `T const x = /* ... */;`, you create a constant, immutable object `x`. Nothing else is needed to make it even more immutable.

That's already exactly your situation. In your case, `T = int[5]`. (Yes, array types *are* types. The size is *part of the type*.)